# Using default values in Python mixed with input parameters

Tags: python, function, default, default-value

I have function that looks like this:

```
def CreateURL(port=8082,ip_addr ='localhost',request='sth'):
    return str("http://" + ip_addr+":"+str(port) + '/' + request)
```

Now I want to use the default parameter for `port` and `request` but not for `ip_addr`. How do I have to write the function in this case?

```
CreateURL('192.168.2.1')
```

Does not work since itwill override the `port` and not the `ip_addr`

Comment: `CreateURL(ip_addr='192.168.2.1')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass the parameter explicitly.

```
>>> def foo(a=1, b=2, c=3):
...     print(a, b, c)
... 
>>> foo(c=4)
(1, 2, 4)
```

Answer (score 3):

`url = CreateURL(ip_addr='192.168.2.1')`

Answer (score 2):

Simply state the name of the parameter you wish to specify like this:

```
>>> CreateURL(ip_addr = '192.168.2.1')
'http://192.168.2.1:8082/sth'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass parameter explicitly

```
>>> CreateURL(ip_addr = "192.168.2.1")
'http://192.168.2.1:8082/sth'
```